# Sort a Query Based on Omitting A Word

Tags: mysql, database, sorting

if I have the following result sets:

```
id, name 
1, The Popper
2, Brittany
3, Fledgler
4, The Nightingale
```

How do I sort them by name so that it disregards the "The" word and sorts the as follows:

```
id, name
1, Britanny
2, Fledler
3, The Nightingale
4, The Popper
```

Thanks in advance. I am using MySQL

Comment: I mean the names must be sorted so that it ignores the word "The"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT id, name
FROM myTable
ORDER BY TRIM(LEADING 'The ' FROM name)
```

More info [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim).

Comment: +1; it's worth mentioning that this will be slow on huge data sets, as it probably won't be able to use indexes.

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT id,title,
    CASE WHEN LOWER(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Title, ' ', 1))
            IN ('a', 'an', 'the')
        THEN CONCAT(
            SUBSTRING(Title, INSTR(Title, ' ') + 1),
            ', ',
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(Title, ' ', 1)
        )
        ELSE Title
    END AS TitleSort
FROM books
ORDER BY TitleSort
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several answers that suggest "live" trimming, which will work fine.

However, if performance is important (*huge* lots of rows) consider having a separate column `title_sort` that contains the title with `The` and other disregarded words already removed.

That way, the database engine can make full use of indexing and other optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

Use this --> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim to remove the "The" from the beginning of the keyword in the Order by clause.